# Changing the Text in Internet Explorer (7.0) title bar and Tab

Tags: internet-explorer, browser

When i open some website, can i as a end-user make the Text printed in the IE title bar at top disappear(make it blank or change it to my own text).
e.g. While typing this question my IE title bar says

**Ask a Question - Stack Overflow - Windows Internet Explorer**

I want to make that blank without at my browser end by way of some IE settings/Windows settings/registry settings etc. Is it possible?

Also is it possible to make the text on IE windows Tab to go blank/customize the text in similar ways??

Just want to keep my SO browsing sessions at work, unnoticed as far as possible!!

-AD

Comment: Is using a different browser an option?

Answer (score 2):

Press F11. This will make the titlebar go away. With my settings also the tabs disappear (autohide or something), so that solves everything for you.

As a side-effect the browser will fill your whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

[KB176497](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176497) pretty much sums it up. (It boils down to: You can't, really.)

How would changing the title of the web page help in terms of "browsing unnoticed" when a simple look into the proxy log would reveal anything you did?

Comment: I dont want my cubicle neighbours to notice my  IE session by looking at title, not the proxy logs!!

Comment: But won't they see the page itself (e.g. prominent logo etc) anyway?

Answer (score 1):

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 SendMessage(
          IntPtr hWnd,
          int Msg,
          int wParam,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lParam);

//Blank out
SendMessage(IEFrameHwnd, 0x000C, 0, "");

Answer (score 0):

You can just switch to Firefox, install Greasemonkey and create a custom script that applies to each and every page, setting the page title to "" an empty string (or " " a one-space string if the first one doesn't work)

That won't remove the title bar text entirely (the browser is still identified), but the page identification both on the title bar and tab will be blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the title to anything you want with SendMessage.
I've done it many times, easily.

The tabs....not so sure.

Comment: @cablehead: How do i use sendmessage to blank out browser title bars? Details?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot remove "Windows Internet Explorer" from the title bar of Internet Explorer except through the registry. There is no javascript that can do this.